# How to get Navicat to ONLY show Default PostgreSQL Database

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, navicat

I have successfully connected to my PostgreSQL Database from Navicat Premium. However, when I open the connection I see a ridiculously long list of databases. I only need (and am only able!) to access one of these databases. I have it listed under my Connection Properties as the Default Database, but it doesn't seem to be opening it automatically. I have to right click on the connection, select 'Open Database', and manually enter the database name. Then, if I am working on multiple databases, I have to scroll through thousands of records to find the one I am looking for. It's a pretty terrible inconvenience.

Does anyone know a trick to hide all but the default database for a Navicat connection? I have been Googling the problem and can't find anything helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the connection properties, selected the "Advanced" tab. Then check the box to "Use advanced connections". Finally check the box to your database. Done.

I thought I might have to use the "Remove DB from List" but I didn't. After doing the steps above, Navicat only shows my database which is exactly what I wanted.

Also I have Navicat Premium Essentials (11.1.7); Purchased through the app store.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect from your DB. Go edit your connection properties. Go to the advanced tab. Click "test connection". Now select the box for advanced connection options. A list of your databases will appear in the box below. Select the DBs you'd like to remove and select "remove DB from list"

Comment: I found that and tried to do it that way, but it won't let me select multiple databases for deletion. I have to do it one at a time, and there are hundreds of them. Is there a quicker way?